# writer.writerow not work for writing multiple CSV in for loop

Tags: python, function, program-entry-point, writer

Please look at the pseudocode below:

```
def main():
    queries = ['A','B','C']
    for query in queries:
        filename = query + '.csv'
        writer = csv.writer(open(filename, 'wt', encoding = 'utf-8'))
        ...
        FUNCTION (query)

def FUNCTION(query):
    ...
    writer.writerow(XXX)
```

I'd like to write to multiple csv files, so I use `for loop` to generate different file names, followed by writing into the file in another `def()`

However, this is not working, the file will be empty.

If I try to get rid of using `main()` or stop `for loop`:

```
writer = csv.writer(open(filename, 'wt', encoding = 'utf-8'))
        ...
FUNCTION (query)
def FUNCTION(query):
       ...
    writer.writerow(XXX)
```

It'll work.

I don't know why? Anything related to `for loop` or `main()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple fix is to pass the file handle and not the name to FUNCTION.  Since the file has been opened in main, you don't need/want the name in the subroutine, just the file handle so change the call to `FUNCTION(writer)` and the definition to

`def FUNCTION(writer):`

and use `writer.writerow(xxx)` wherever you need to stream output in the subroutine.

Note: you changed the name of the file pointer from `writer` to `write` in your example.

Comment: Works like magic! This is cool lesson for me learn to pass file handle!

Answer (score 0):

I think the possible reason is you didn't close the file pointer. You can use the context manager like:

```
with open(filename, 'wt', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    ...
    FUNCTION (query)
```

which will help you auto close file.